# Entity Framework linq to SQL relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

table person
personid
personname

table customer
customerid
personid
orderinfo

I am entity framework and want to select few columns but on join I am unable to join customer and person table based on personid. all foreign key and primary keys are in place

```
var dealercontacts = from contact in database.person join dealer in database.customer on contact.personid equals dealer.personid
                                 select personname, orderinfo;
```

I am receiving error that customer  does not contain personid

Answer (score 3):

If all of your foreign keys are setup correctly, you should be able to call it as such:

```
var dealercontacts = from contact in database.person
select contact.personname, contact.customer.orderinfo
```

Does this work to solve your problem?

EDIT: You may have to switch the query around and write it as such:

```
var dealercontacts = from customer in database.customers
select customer.person.personname, customer.orderinfo
```